# Como devolver correctamente la palabra?

Tags: javascript

```js
function ordenar(string){
  var abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
      to = abc.split(''),
      str = string.split('');
      
      for(let i=0;i<to.length;i++){
         for(let j=0;j<str.length;j++){
           if(str[j] == to[i]) console.log(to[i]);
         }
      }
}

ordenar('hola');
```

**Como pueden ver en consola muestra `ahlo`, pero yo quiero que muestre como originalmente era `hola` , cual es el error o como debería hacerse?**

Comment: Estas ordenando o desordenando la palabra? No entiendo...

Comment: Solo quiero que me devuelva la string como era, pero dentro el recorrido del array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El flujo de tu codigo deberia de ser alrevez por que la primera letra de la variable `abc` es `a`, lo que significa que el segundo bucle, buscara en cada letra de la variable `string` la palabra `a` que es la numero 4 y lo imprimira de primero.

Poniendolo siemple, si inviertes el for, te funcionara perfecto:

```js
function ordenar(string){
  var abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
      to = abc.split(''),
      str = string.split('');
      
    for(let j=0; j<str.length; j++)
    {
      for(let i=0; i< to.length; i++)
      { 
           if(str[j] == to[i]) 
           {
              console.log(to[i]);
              break;// detenemos el for
            }
         }
      }
}

ordenar('hola');
```